# Creat db snapshot of a db in restoring state

Tags: sql-server, snapshot

Is it possible to create a snapshot of a SQL db that is in a restoring state?

Comment: See prerequisites here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot. The database has to be online.

As Scott [referenced](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx)

[image]